# How to align children of listview in the same level?

Tags: listview, flutter

I want to align the children of listview on the same level as the center-right, I use the below code:

```
body: Container(
        child: ReorderableListView(
          onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
            setState(() {
              _updateItems(oldIndex, newIndex);
            });
          },
          children: [
            for (final item in data)
              Card(
                key: ValueKey(item),
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    value: true,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() {
                        value = !value;
                      });
                    },
                    title: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text(
                        '$item',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

But the result is this image:

[image]

As you can see some children have more right space than others, how can fix this issue, please help me, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the data you are using? It seems like the problem is the data, try using the trim method as follows: `title: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text(
                        '${item.toString().trim()}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this fixes it I tried to reproduce the problem and I really can't but this seemed to help a little.

```
 Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      '$item',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work just fine. It seems there is some spacing in the data as Luis has mentioned in the comment.

I just used your code and put some random data.

[image]